# HttpWebRequest webservice call returns Request format is invalid: text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Tags: c#

Trying to call WebService using HTTPWebRequest and posting data, it results in invalid request format, I have added http verbs post in both client and webservice, any ideas here ?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WS/test.asmx/GetData");
String xmlString =  "Montreal";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] bytesToWrite = encoding.GetBytes(xmlString);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = bytesToWrite.Length;
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
newStream.Close();  //fails here with error message Request format is invalid: text/xml;charset=UTF-8.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
```

Comment: You aren't writing valid XML to the stream...

Comment: You're also using a UTF-8 content type, but are using ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I got to modify the approach, this worked for me.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WS/test.asmx");
String xmlData = "Montréal";
String xmlString = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><soapenv:Header/>  <soapenv:Body><tem:GetData><tem:data>" + xmlData + "</tem:data></tem:GetData></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = bytesToWrite.Length;
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8;";
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
newStream.Close();
try
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string msg = ex.Message;
}
```